# Java-Spark-Drools : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a default KieBase

Tags: java, apache-spark, drools, kie

I have below code which is calling **drools rule engine** from spark.

**Spark Version : 2.3.0**

```
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            ClassTag<KieBase> classTagTest = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(KieBase.class);
            Broadcast<KieBase> broadcastRules = context.broadcast(kContainer.getKieBase(), classTagTest);
            finalJoined.foreach(row -> droolprocess(broadcastRules.value(),row));
```

here `finalJoined` is of type `Dataset<Row>`

```
public static void droolprocess(KieBase base,Row row){
        StatelessKieSession session = base.newStatelessKieSession();
                //some code to fire rules.
}
```

When I am running this code in eclipse I am getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a default KieBase
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:336)
    at com.sample.Transformation.main(Transformation.java:66)
```

**My analysis :**

due to method of `SparkContext`

```
public <T> Broadcast<T> broadcast(T value,
                                  scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$11)
```

It is causing issue because I have to pass `KieBase` as serializable and it is generated at runtime so issue is coming. However I am not sure if this is correct analysis.

**kmodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="dtables" packages="dtables">
        <ksession name="ksession-dtables"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="process" packages="process">
        <ksession name="ksession-process"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Can someone provide rootcause and probable way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `kmodule.xml` file you are defining 3 `KieBases` with 3 different names. So far so good. Now, when you want to get a `KieBase` from the `KieContainer`, you need to specify the name of the `KieBase` you want. If you don't specify one, Drools will look for the default `KieBase` in your `kmodule.xml` file. If you don't have any default `KieBase`, Drools will fail with the Exception you are having.

So, either you define what your default `KieBase` is: `<kbase name="rules" packages="rules" default="true">...`

Or you specify what `KieBase` you want: `... context.broadcast(kContainer.getKieBase("rules"), classTagTest);`

Hope it helps,

Comment: It does help. Thanks :)